# Answers getting posted as comments

Tags: discussion

When browsing through the Unanswered Questions section of WordPress SE, I come across an overwhelming amount of supposedly 'unanswered' questions, which have actually have a perfectly reasonable answer posted in the comments, or as part of the question itself.

I propose that something be done about this - be it an option to migrate a comment to an answer, or a setting to mark a question as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this answer](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/automated-down-votes/1155#1155) for some guidance. In short:

- Leave a comment, ask to move the solution to a real answer.
- Come back two weeks later and either

  - vote up the new answer, or
  - “steal” the answer. That is absolutely acceptable.

We cannot convert comments to answers, only the other way works. And the asker only can mark a question as answered.