# What's the etiquette for Community-bumped questions?

Tags: discussion

I understand the reasoning for bumping them, but I wonder what the best course of action is when there is not clear "good answer" to upvote and it's not a trivial thing to answer. I read through [Let's get the unanswered rate under control](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4193/lets-get-the-unanswered-rate-under-control), which is related but doesn't answer the question for me.

Some of them are a couple of years old and very specific to one user's problems, so I figure while they might appreciate an answer for sentimental reasons, they've most likely moved on with life and solved the problem another way or abandonded the mission that lead them on this path of despair.

Others would need more information from the OP.

Still others might be related to ancient versions and solving them today might just be an academic challenge for historians.

I feel like I might do more harm than good by disturbing what has been at peace for so long and possibly start a discussion about something nobody cares about any longer.

Is there a consensus on what to do when you bump into these? Do I just ignore them? Should I flag them? How do you handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So seems like there is no consensus. Personally, I downvote questions that are too localized, plugin specific etc as it will be very hard to close vote them as the time period for the "close voting" before it expires is much shorter than when the question is fresh.